# What is a normal filter on a partially-ordered set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, lattice-orders, filters

I'm familiar with the concept of a **filter** *F* on a partially-ordered set: a non-empty downward directed (any two elements in *F* have a common lower bound) upper set (all elements above an element in *F* are also in *F*) and that a filter is **proper** if it's not the entire partially-ordered set.

What I cannot seem to find is a consistent definition of a **normal filter** on a partially-ordered set. I've seen only a couple, which didn't agree.

Where can I find a solid, accepted definition of a normal filter?

Comment: Closed under diagonal intersections?

Comment: Could you explain what that means, precisely? That's the part that the authors I've reviewed haven't seemed to agree upon.

Comment: What different versions have you seen, and what sources are you consulting? I would imagine $\bigtriangleup_a X_a=\{t\mid\forall b<t\,(t\in X_b)\}$, but I can also imagine that if your application requires something similar but slightly different, you would change the definition to suit your needs.

Comment: In Gratzer's "Lattice theory" in one of the exercises there is a notion of a **normal ideal**. Call an ideal $I$ of lattice $L$ *normal* if $I = (I^{\text{ub}})^{\text{lb}}$, where $A^\text{ub}$ is the set of all upper bounds of $A$ and similarly for $A^\text{lb}$. This is connected with the MacNeille completion of $L$, which is the lattice of all normal ideals. This definition works for posets as well and I guess normal filters are defined dually.